# How to create a script on windows which could run ssh command on a remote linux

Tags: linux

I just want to create a auto script on windows which could do run some comand through ssh on a reomote linux.

I know it's easy to write script between linux(ssh client) and linux(ssh server).

But I do not know how to create a script on windows(ssh client) to remote connect to linux(ssh server)

Answer (score 1):

Most popular languages have ssh libraries you can use, pick a language you are familiar with and then go library hunting.

I've used these with success:

C - [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/)
.NET - [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx)
Python - [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/)  or [Really Simple SSH](http://zeth.net/archive/2008/05/29/sftp-python-really-simple-ssh/) or [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/0.9.1/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

If it's just some command lines you want to run then [plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) will be enough IMHO..

Goodluck.

Answer (score 1):

use [plink](http://linux.die.net/man/1/plink) (get it from putty website) and a bat file format like this:

```
Plink.exe -ssh -pw %password5 %linuxuser%@%servver% /path/to/script/script.sh
```

Save em in same folder -> run your awesome masterpiece

Answer (score 0):

One way is to install Cygwin and use a shell script to run ssh commands. You can launch this script by running `sh.exe` with arguments.

This way, you can do the job with the same Linux tools (sh and OpenSSH) that you are already familiar with.